# The mapping of a Set onto the characteristic function is a bijection

Tags: analysis

Let $X$ be a Set. For all Subsets $ A \subset X$ the characteristic function of A is defined as:

\begin{align}
\chi_A(x)= \begin{cases} 1 \iff x \in A \\ 0 \iff x \notin A \end{cases}
\end{align}
Let $\lbrace0,1\rbrace^X$ be the Set of functions $ X \longrightarrow \lbrace 0,1\rbrace  $. Further let $P(X)$ be the power set of $X$.

Show that the following function is a bijection:
\begin{align}
P(X) & \longrightarrow \lbrace 0,1\rbrace ^X \\
A & \longmapsto \chi_A
 \end{align}
I have struggled with this problem for a few days now and I believe one of my biggest issues is to create the desired set $\lbrace0,1\rbrace^X$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496429/showing-mathcalpx-is-isomorphic-to-2x

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275904/bijection-f-mathcalpa-toa-to-0-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$P$ is injective:** Let $A,B$ be two sets with $\chi_A=\chi_B$. Then $\chi_{A\backslash B}=\chi_A-\chi_B = 0$ and thus $A\subseteq B$. In the same way $B\subseteq A$.

**$P$ is surjective:** Let $f\in\{0,1\}^X$, i.e. $f:X\rightarrow\{0,1\}$. Define the set $C =\{x\in X|f(x)=1\}$. Then $f=\chi_C$.